# How to retrieve a value for a particular key in Python dictionary when key is not enclosed in quotes?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that prints like:

```
{A: Adam, B: Bob}
```

now when I try to print the value of 'B' key by the following code I am getting KeyError.

```
print dictionary['B']
```

This is because my keys in the dictionary are not enclosed within quotations.

How can I come over this?

Comment: `now when I try to print the value of 'B' key` then why you try to print `print dict['A']`?

Comment: post the actual dictionary.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Updated it.

Comment: B and 'B' are not the same

Comment: As Photon already mentioned, B is not a string, but 'B' is. Hence B is not equal to 'B'

Comment: Yeah.. I got that. But then when I try dict[B], Pyhton looks for a variable as B in the program and I get an error. So I was wondering if there is a way on how to retrieve values for these kind of dictionaries where the keys are not enclosed within quotes.
Sorry.. I will be more explicit from next time when I write a question.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by Photon, `B` and `'B'` are not equal and you can have the following:

```
foo = {A: Adam, B: Bob, 'B', 'small bob'}
```

Which is totally fine with the dictionary

Comment: Please don't use `dict` as it is the built-in dictionary type.